# Links are not focused on tab pressed in safari

Tags: tabs, safari, keyboard, focus

Links are not focused if span placed inside anchor tag on tab pressed in safari while focus working in other browser.

The following is my code

```
<a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
```

If i remove span, the focus will go to home on tab pressed, if i don't remove, focus is not working.

But this is working in other browser.

**Note : I've enabled the option that Press Tab to highlight each item on a webpage**